# ensure embed code (iframe) is only used on customer web sites

Tags: html, security, iframe

I have a service and would like clients to be able to place this service on their website. I am looking at doing this by using an iframe. I will provide the code and they can just copy and paste the code to show the functionality. Each client will be discovered by the query string.

There is a concern that anyone can look at the source of the website, copy the iframe and add it to their own website therefore using the service and charging the original client. I obviously want to stop this.

Ideally, I would like to verify that the website that is using the iframe is linked to the client who registered to use the service. Is this possible at all? I know there are issues with cross domain security.

If it isn't possible, I guess I would need to create a widget instead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For each client, have a whitelist of web sites that can embed the iframe. Then check the ['referer' header](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_referer) against that list whenever the page inside the iframe is loaded.

Or if http headers prove to be unreliable try using javascript, via `parent.document.location.href`

Comment: I've seen on other posts that the referer is unreliable. Is this true?

Comment: Yes, some web browsers will omit the header entirely. But you don't need 100% reliability, just enough to make it not worth stealing your widget ;)